# Как при помощи canvas сделать картинку круглой?

Tags: canvas, javascript, html5

Здравствуйте. Как при помощи HTML5, canvas и JavaScript загрузить картинку и сделать ее круглой (без искажения изображения, просто обрезать края и закруглить)?

**PS**:
Без использования каких-либо библиотек.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В HTML5 при помощи canvas, закруглить картинку оказалось немного сложнее, чем я предполагал. Шарясь по гуглу, у меня возникло ощущение, что при помощи canvas, все обычно только чертят всякие там градиенты, линии, кружочки и т.д. Потому что другого очень мало. И то, как сделать круглой картинку, я догадался только прочитав пару глав из книги `Дронов.В - HTML 5 CSS 3 и Web 2.0.....`. Ну так вот, приведу пример, где генерируется `data url` итоговой картинки, которую впредь можно ставить куда угодно.

```
<body>
<img onclick="build(this)" id="face1" src="resources/imgs/ico-twitter.png"/>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:640px;height:480px;">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function build(caller){
        var image = getMergedUrl(document.getElementById("face1"));
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = image;
        document.getElementById("map_canvas").appendChild(img);
    }
    function getMergedUrl(img){
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        //Рисуем окружность. Радиус возьмем по высоте
        ctx.beginPath();
        //x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise
        ctx.arc(img.width/2, img.height/2, img.height/2, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();//рисуем закрашенную фигуру.
        /*теперь задаем наложение для картинки. При таком наложении,отображается только та часть новой фигуры, которая накладыва-
        ется на старую. Остальные части новой и старой фигур не выводятся;*/
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Вот что в итоге получится после одного нажатия на нашу картинку:

[image]

И еще. Из-за какой-то там  политики безопасности, метод "`toDataURL()`", будет работать только в текущем домене. Ну и у меня почему-то не работает на локальном компьютере.

Comment: А на локальном не работает везде или только в FireFox?

Comment: В гугл хроме тоже не сработало. И в Сафари.

Comment: @Дарья, под локальным он, вероятно, имеет в виду `file://`. Потому что http(s) будет работать одинаково для локального и внешнего.